# Nodejs concatenating numbers as a string

Tags: node.js, vue.js, parsing, numbers

This function is triggered on button click

```
nextPage() {
  this.tweets = []
  this.$route.query.page += 1
  this.getTweets()
},
```

What it's doing is resetting array of tweets to zero, incrementing existing query(page) by 1 and calling getTweets function

```
getTweets(newCurrent) {
      this.tweets = []
      const API_URL = `${this.$server}/api/twitter/tweets`

      const params = {
        token: getUserToken(),
        // THIS IS WHERE I AM PASSING QUERY
        page: this.$route.query.page,
        newCurrentPage: newCurrent,
      }
      axios.post(API_URL, null, { params }).then(res => {
        this.currentPage = res.data.page
        this.numberOfPages = res.data.numberOfPages

        res.data.tweets.forEach(tweet => {
          const tweetData = {
            id: tweet.id,
            tweet_text: tweet.tweet_text,
            twitter_name: tweet.twitter_name,
            twitter_username: tweet.twitter_username,
            added_at: moment(String(tweet.added_at)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm'),
          }
          this.tweets.push(tweetData)
        })
      })
    }
```

And then finally in nodejs. Here I am getting typeof number but currentPage is still concatenated, if I were on page 20 and I click next, currentPage will be 201. How to avoid this?

```
    var currentPage = parseInt(req.query.page)
    console.log(typeof currentPage)
    console.log(currentPage)
    
    // check if there is newCurrentPage
    if(newCurrentPage != undefined) {
        skip = (newCurrentPage - 1) * pageSize
        currentPage = newCurrentPage
    } else {
        // check if page is valid
        if(currentPage < 1) {
            currentPage = 1
        } else if(currentPage > numberOfPages) {
            currentPage = numberOfPages - 1
        }
        
        // offset
        skip = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query parameters in vue-router are always treated as `string`. Because it can be `page=1` like it could be `page=foo`, there is no way to know.

So `?page=1` will be `this.$route.query.page === "1"`

To fix this, you'll have to parse the parameter first:

```
const newPage = parseInt(this.$route.query.page, 10) + 1
```

---

Side note, assigning a new value to `$router.query.page` doesn't work. You have to push a new route for it to update:

```
const newPage = parseInt(this.$route.query.page, 10) + 1
this.$router.push({ query: newPage })
```